# eTA/Transit Visa for US connections in YVR-International Terminal

Tags: eta, yvr

I am flying AirCanada from Hong Kong -> Vancouver -> Seattle on an Indian passport with a valid US visa. I do not have a Canadian visa of any sort.

Does Vancouver have sterile transit for connections entirely in the International Terminal? Do I need to clear CBSA immigration (eTA/transit visa) before I reach US pre-clearance.

Comment: The question of sterile connection is irrelevant in Canada. You either need a transit visa or you don't.

Comment: Welcome new user.   Be careful of this disaster:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122537/september-2018-how-long-are-canadian-etas-taking